# Java 7 installation error

Tags: java, software-installation

I'm getting this output when i try to install oracle-java7 from webupd8 ppa

```
Download done.
Removing outdated cached downloads...
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
Oracle JDK 7 is NOT installed.
dpkg: error processing oracle-java7-installer (--configure):
 subprocess installed post-installation script returned error exit status 1
Setting up gsfonts-x11 (0.22) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 oracle-java7-installer
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Could you describe the exact commands that you tried, also, the command you used to get that error.

Comment: it seems the webupd8 ppa is running into issues https://twitter.com/pdeva/status/444960868917194752

Comment: You should mark one of the answers provided below

Comment: There may also be some proxy related issue. Check if you can connect to internet directly or should you define some proxy config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I download source file from Oracle's website and installed manually from scratch... It is working well now ... The solution I used is [here](http://www.printandweb.ca/2013/04/manually-install-oracle-jdk-7-for.html)

The instructions given are as follows and should be updated for the current version:

> > Download Java SE 7 JDK for Linux x86 archive. At the time of writing,
> >     the file I'm using is jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz, but the filename
> >     will change as updates are released. Apparently there is no longer a
> >     jvm folder, so create one.
>
> `sudo mkdir /usr/lib/jvm`
>
> > Move the archive to the jvm folder
>
> `sudo mv jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz /usr/lib/jvm/`
>
> > Change to the jvm folder and extract the JDK from the archive
>
> `cd /usr/lib/jvm`
>
> `sudo tar zxvf jdk-7u21-linux-i586.tar.gz`
>
> > Everything will be extracted to a new jdk1.7.0_21 folder and you can
> >     delete the archive file now. Make symbolic links to the new java
> >     binary.
>
> `sudo ln -s -b /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/java /etc/alternatives/java`
>
> `sudo ln -s -b /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0_21/jre/bin/java /usr/bin/java`
>
> > Double-check the version
>
> `java -version`

Answer (score 12):

I face same problem and get in a solution:

1. Download the JDK [here](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/downloads/jdk7-downloads-1880260.html).
2. Then go to `/var/cache/oracle-jdk7-installer/`
3. In that dir remove `jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz` and paste the version downloaded from Oracle website.
4. Try `sudo apt-get install oracle-java7-installer` again.. this time should work fine!

Comment: Upvoted. I think this is the most correct and simple way to solve the problem. I hope the webupd8 guys will issue an updated package solving this issue soon.

Comment: You should probably try to contact them and let them know ;)

Comment: This works for those who want an easy update process, thought the solution suggested here http://askubuntu.com/a/434891/112263 can be used for those who want a way to manually update their java...

Comment: FOR JDK8 - do apt-get install oracle-java8-installer, it would work automatically without the need to mess with /var

Answer (score 2):

This is the key:

```
sha256sum mismatch jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz
```

The file `jdk-7u51-linux-x64.tar.gz` has been corrupted and fails to validate against the expected hash. Try downloading it again, that might fix your issue.

Comment: this may be due to not updating prior to installing. I know I was able to easily use the webupd8team/java ppa on a freshly installed system with auto updates but ran in this problem on the system that requires manual updates...